# call async function on given paramater and keep running it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kinda stuck on a really dumb problem. I have two asnyc functions for displaying satellite position, one async fucntion is with satellite icon and the other is without satellite icon. Now when I click a certain a link, I want to keep calling that async function, but I'm stuck on how to set up a condition statement for this thing. I've been stuck a bit here and keep on failing. The original one needs to be called when first loading the page.

I also have a question on how to solve this problem for multiple scenarios with switch cases, in case I want to add few other options or what is the general best technique/approach to use for multiple options.

```
<h1>Where is the ISS?</h1>

        <p>
            latitude: <span id="lat"></span>°<br>
            longitude: <span id="lon"></span>°
        </p>

        <div>
            <a class="link" id="change1" onclick="change();" href="">Change 1 </a>|
            <a class="link" href=""> Change 2 </a>|
            <a class="link" href=""> Change 3</a>
        </div>
        
        <?php 
            
        ?>
        <div id="issMap"></div>
        <div id="issMap2"></div>
    <?php }
    ?>




<script>

    window.onload = function original() {
    //Making map and tiles
    const mymap = L.map('issMap').setView([0, 0], 1);

    const issIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: "iss200.png",
        iconSize: [75, 75],
        
    });

    const marker = L.marker([ 0, 0 ], {icon: issIcon}).addTo(mymap);

    const attribution = '&copy: <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';

    const tileUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    const tiles = L.tileLayer(tileUrl, { attribution });
    tiles.addTo(mymap);
    const api_url = 'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544';

    let firstTime = true;

    async function getISS() {
        const response = await fetch(api_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        const { latitude, longitude } = data;

        //L.marker([ latitude, longitude ]).addTo(mymap);
        marker.setLatLng([latitude, longitude]);
        if (firstTime) {
            mymap.setView([latitude, longitude], 5);
            firstTime = false;
        }
        //console.log(latitude);
        //console.log(data.latitude), if we don't destructure
        document.getElementById('lat').textContent = latitude.toFixed(3);
        document.getElementById('lon').textContent = longitude.toFixed(3);
        
    }
    
    getISS();

    setInterval(getISS, 1000);

    }
   
    function change() {
        //Making map and tiles
        const mymap = L.map('issMap2').setView([0, 0], 1);

        const marker = L.marker([ 0, 0 ]).addTo(mymap);

        const attribution = '&copy: <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';

        const tileUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
        const tiles = L.tileLayer(tileUrl, { attribution });
        tiles.addTo(mymap);
        const api_url = 'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544';

        let firstTime = true;

        async function getISS() {
            const response = await fetch(api_url);
            const data = await response.json();
            const { latitude, longitude } = data;

            //L.marker([ latitude, longitude ]).addTo(mymap);
            marker.setLatLng([latitude, longitude]);
            if (firstTime) {
                mymap.setView([latitude, longitude], 5);
                firstTime = false;
            }
            //console.log(latitude);
            //console.log(data.latitude), if we don't destructure
            document.getElementById('lat').textContent = latitude.toFixed(3);
            document.getElementById('lon').textContent = longitude.toFixed(3);
        }

        getISS();

        setInterval(getISS, 1000);
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: You're declaring two getISS functions. Would it better create just one and pass parameter to It? This way you can reuse your function.

Comment: yeah that's what I'm trying to do, sorry if it was missleading.